# Почему проверяется length value input не по условию?

Tags: javascript, input, button, submit

Если длина символов меньше 12 -> `innerHTML`, иначе `continue` (не выполняет корректно )
Есть второй вопрос: если `inp.onclick = null` отключает клик, когда условие верно, то как вернуть клик, когда условие не верно?

```
inp = document.querySelector('form input:nth-of-type(2)');//Проверяемый инпут
    inp.onclick = function(){
        inp.value = '+79';

        if(inp.value.length != 0){
            inp.onclick = null;
        }
    }

sbm = document.querySelector('form button');//кнопка submit
out = document.querySelector('output');//вывод сообщения

    sbm.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(inp.value.length < 12){
            out.innerHTML = 'Мало символов, давай еще жмот(example)!';
        }else{
            continue
        }
    }
```

Comment: что значит _проверяется length value input не по условию?_

Comment: Это значит, что длина value инпута если меньше 12 или больше (вообще любое количество) -> continue происходит

Comment: [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) может находиться **только** внутри цикла.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sbm.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(inp.value.length < 12){
        out.innerHTML = 'Мало символов, давай еще жмот(example)!';
    }else{
        continue
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на **e.preventDefault();**

```
inp = document.querySelector('form input:nth-of-type(2)');//Проверяемый инпут
inp.onclick = function(){
    inp.value = '+79';

    if(inp.value.length != 0){
        inp.onclick = null;
    }
}
```

Скажите зачем тут это условие? Если результат всегда один?

Comment: По клику вставляется три символа, их можно удалить (допустим) и если длина value менее 3х (их удалили например) -> вставить (выполнить функцию опять) и наоборот, если 3 символа и больше -> null. Насчет "обратить внимание на..." так и не понял что там?

Comment: я понял я понял

Comment: выложите исправленный код )

Comment: Должно быть так, но критика приветствуется. у меня работает

Comment: с  e.preventDefault(); - я тут "перебдел", проверил там нормально работало, только лишний код и точки с запятой для красоты не хватало :) Удачи Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать

```
sbm.onclick = function(e){
    if(inp.value.length < 12){
        out.innerHTML = 'Мало символов, давай еще жмот(example)!';
        return false
    }
}
```